# Problems with custom CIFilter and kernels

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm working on a custom filter that should combine to pictures using a blending mode but I have a problem.

The kernel looks like this.

```
kernel vec4 brightnessEffect (sampler background_src, sampler foreground_src)
{
    vec4 colorDodgeValue;

    vec4 currentSourceBackground;
    vec4 currentSourceForeground;    
    currentSourceBackground = sample(background_src, samplerCoord(background_src));
    currentSourceForeground = sample(foreground_src, samplerCoord(foreground_src));

    colorDodgeValue = currentSourceBackground; //1
    //colorDodgeValue = currentSourceForeground; //2
    return colorDodgeValue;
}
```

I get a crash when I run it, if I comment line 2 and uncomment line 1 it works just fine.
Any ideas?